# 'routerLink' or 'this.router.navigate' not working for some users

Tags: angular

I have an angular application. I am providing part of the code that is relevant to my question.
The problem I am facing is that for one of the users

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', n.userID]">{{n.userID}}</a>
```

or

```
<button (click)="this.router.navigate(['/user',n.userID]);" style="color:blue">{{n.userID}}</button>
```

doesn't seem to be working. As the user clicks on the user id, it seems he is getting redirected to the home page

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

The issue is not happening with other users.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { OktaAuthGuard } from '@okta/okta-angular';
import { OktaCallbackComponent } from './callback/callback.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error/error.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { UserDetailComponent } from './components/user-detail/user-detail.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './components/user-list/user-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'callback', component: OktaCallbackComponent },
{ canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], path: 'userList/:pm', component: UserListComponent },
{ canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], path: 'userList', component: UserListComponent },
{ canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], path: 'user/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },  
{ canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**user-list.component.html**

```
<div>
    <label><u>List of Users</u></label>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table1">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color:#03036e;height:50px;color:white;">
                        <th style="width:10%">User ID</th>
                        <th style="width:30%">User Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <!-- -->
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let n of activePageDataChunk;let i = index">                            
                        <td>
                            <!--<button (click)="this.router.navigate(['/user',n.userID]);" style="color:blue">{{n.userID}}</button>  -->
                            <a [routerLink]="['/user', n.userID]">{{n.userID}}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{n.userName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**user-list.component.ts**

```
.......
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(@Inject(OKTA_AUTH) public oktaAuth: OktaAuth, private fb: UntypedFormBuilder, public router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
.....}
```

Can somebody help, please? Thanks!

**Update**

I replaced

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', n.userID]">{{n.userID}}</a>
```

with

```
<input type="button" (click)="gotoUserDetail(n.userID);" style="color:blue" value={{n.userID}}
```

but again, this works for me but not for the user.

```
gotoUserDetail(s:any){
 console.log("get user detail with id: "+s); //log
 this.router.navigate(['/user/' + s]);
}
```

The console log in gotoUserDetail() is not happening on click of button for the user. I tried both Chrome and Edge. Both do not seem to be working. Is it possible that something is blocking user action on his machine?

Comment: There could also be an unrelated issue where your app crashes and falls back to homepage. Anything in the console ? also make sure the user is properly authenticated with oktaAuth and has an ID.

Comment: Thank you @wadie! I investigated a lot and don't see anything in the console logs. The user is authenticated and the app doesn't seem to be crashing. The user list page is the home page for the user, so the user remains on the same page. I tried replacing the router navigation with a button that should invoke a function on click. There is a log statement in the function which is not getting logged. I am now wondering that is it that something is blocking clicks on the user's machine?